# Solve the diff eq $y'=\cos(x-y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos(x-y)$$

So I know I need to make the substitution $u=x-y$ but then what's $du$, is it $du=dx-dy$?

Or do I rewrite $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}$$

Really stuck on this one.

Comment: @Moo but where do I go from there ?

Comment: Did either of you two actually read OP's question? >_>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to note that when $u = x - y$ ($x$ being the independent variable) you have that $u' = 1-y'$, i.e. $y' = 1-u'$. The equation then becomes $u' = 1 - \cos u$. This is an equation with separable variables that is given implicitly by
$$
-\cot \frac u2 = x + C
$$

You can also have constant solutions $u = u_0$ whenever $\cos u_0 =1$. Below you can find a stream plot for this equation ($u$), and for the original equation ($y$).
[image]

[image]

Comment: that's what I had!! so $\frac{du}{dx}=1-\cos u$ and solve from there?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Yes, that is it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't overthink things. In this context, $y$ is a function of $x$; finding $du$ amounts to first finding $u'$, and clearly

$$u(x) = x - y(x) \implies \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} x - \frac{d}{dx} y(x) = 1 - y'$$

and therefore

$$du = (1 - y') dx$$

Comment: Which, if it helps intuition, can be thought of as $dx-dy$.

Comment: @preferred_anon thanks! what I was thinking as well lol :)

Comment: Then where do I go from here, do I substitute $dy$ for $dx-du$?